# Data not inserted using hibernate, but gives no error?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to get started with Hibernate, but can't insert data, for some reason. It seems to be working properly as no error is given, but when I check the database the table is empty. I don't think it the connection to the database itself that fail, because when I change the table name to a non-excisting one in the mapping xml, Hibernate creates this on the fly (But as I said, no data is inserted). Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Here's my code:

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
          <property     name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intex</property>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
          <property name="show_sql">true</property>
          <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
          <!-- Mapping files -->
          <mapping resource="intex.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My mapping xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.intex.uni.courses.Course" table="course">
   <id name="id" column="id" >
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>

  <property name="name" column="name" />
  <property name="description" column="description" />
  <property name="url" column="url" />
  <property name="code" column="code" />
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my test client:

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = null;

        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Course course = new Course();
            course.setDescription("Description");
            course.setName("NAME");
            course.setUrl("http://www.url.com");
            session.save(course);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I really hope someone will be able to help me! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you also post the SQL that Hibernate generates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code and test in main class.

```
Session session = null;
Transaction txn = null;
try {  
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
        new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    txn = session.beginTransaction();
    Course course = new Course();  
    course.setDescription("Description");
    course.setName("NAME");
    course.setUrl("http://www.url.com"); 
    session.save(course); 
    txn.commit();

} catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (!txn.wasCommitted()) {
        txn.rollback();
    }

    session.flush();  
    session.close();   
}
```

Comment: should not this transaction management be done automatically?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that the system is not committing the transaction that includes the needed insert. I always set transactions explicitly e.g. [Hibernate Getting Started Tutorial Example 2.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-test)

An alternative is that you should be able to set Hibernate's commit mode in you code so that transactions are implicit - look at [FlushMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-flushing)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = null;
        Transaction txn = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            txn = session.beginTransaction();
            Course course = new Course();
            course.setDescription("Description");
            course.setName("NAME");
            course.setUrl("http://www.url.com");
            session.save(course);
            txn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please start transaction before save and commit transaction after save.

Answer (score 0):

Check mapping file if any generator is defined. comment the generator and check.
This solution worked for me.